# What's the role of the method-override middleware in Express 4?

Tags: node.js, express

Since the `Router` object in Express 4 supports:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.delete('/route', function(req, res) {
    //...
};

router.put('/route', function(req, res) {
    //...
};
```

What use is there for method-override middleware? Can I safely remove it from my `app.js` and `package.json`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `methodOverride()` middleware is for requests from clients that only natively support simple verbs like GET and POST. So in those cases you could specify a special query field (or a hidden form field for example) that indicates the real verb to use instead of what was originally sent. That way your backend `.put()`/`.delete()`/`.patch()`/etc. routes don't have to change and will still work and you can accept requests from all kinds of clients.

Comment: Realistically speaking, which existing clients do not support those verbs? Taking into account most of the world uses either a modern browser, or a mobile browser that relies on WebKit?

Comment: GET and POST are the only supported verbs for forms, even in HTML5 (for now). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/166501).

Comment: what about 2019 please?

Comment: What about 2020, please?

Comment: Nothing has changed for HTML5 in 2019 or 2020 as far as permitted HTTP verbs in HTML forms.

Answer (score 1):

Provides faux HTTP method support.

Pass an optional key to use when checking for
a method override, otherwise defaults to _method.
The original method is available via req.originalMethod.

- String key
- returns Function

**Source**

```
module.exports = function methodOverride(key){
  key = key || "_method";
  return function methodOverride(req, res, next) {
    var method;
    req.originalMethod = req.originalMethod || req.method;

    // req.body
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && key in req.body) {
      method = req.body[key].toLowerCase();
      delete req.body[key];
    }

    // check X-HTTP-Method-Override
    if (req.headers['x-http-method-override']) {
      method = req.headers['x-http-method-override'].toLowerCase();
    }

    // replace
    if (supports(method)) req.method = method.toUpperCase();

    next();
  };
};
```

### supports()

Check if node supports method.

**Source**

```
function supports(method) {
  return ~methods.indexOf(method);
}
```